# Submit a form going forbidden when some inline style defined

Tags: php, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

In a form textarea, when I am trying to put the following, on submit it is going to forbidden

```
This is a <span style="color:#ff0000;">normal</span> text.
```

The error is showing :
**Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

but If I try the following instead, there is showing no problem. Only issue when some style definition is added

```
This is a <span class="myclass">normal</span> text.
```

I have tried both get and post, the error is same. No inline style definition is accepted when the from is submited.

Comment: Where are you posting this to?

Comment: Could it be the `#`? Have you tried with some inline style not being a color, like `style="width:10px;"`

Comment: @D Malan - I am posting this to the same page

Comment: @Michel - No that is not happening, I have tested with the following

>> This is a <span style="">normal</span> text. >>

If I write this above, this will return into error. But If I write

>> This is a <span style>normal</span> text. >> 
or 
>> This is a <span class="myclass">normal</span> text.</code> >>  
It is making the post properly. This behavior is so strange. For example I have set a sample link for testing the above : >> http://fishpanna.com/test/index.php >> 
You can try to post my above lines there to see the issue. It would only print_r the post.

Comment: Can you show the PHP code for receiving the POST?

Comment: Tested with multiple browsers. On my own server all is ok. On your page the data is send. It goes wrong with `style=`, but also with `<html></html>` and `<iframe src="">`. So I suspect it's on your server, either in the server settings or in the way you handle the Post values and output them.

Comment: <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);exit;
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test for access</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="margin:5% 35%;padding:20px;border:#ccc 1px solid;">
 <form method="post">
 <textarea name="content" style="resize:vertical;width:100%;height:250px;"></textarea><br /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Michel - yes this is simplest script, nothing fancy at all there, I have pasted the whole page script above and I am sure it is the server property which is blocking the style="" definition. But what is that property in server ? I am trying to understand what should I ask to the hosting to fix ?

Comment: The 403 is just a redirect to a not existing/not accessible page. I'd suggest excluding PHP errors first. Put on error-reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);set_error_handler('e_handler',E_ALL);function e_handler($a,$b,$c,$d){echo $a.' '.$b.' '.$c.' '.$d;die;}` Then surround the `echo` with `ob_start() ... ob_get_contents()` and write it to a file with `file_put_contents()`. See if there's something strange in there.

Comment: @Michel - did that, changed the code like the following >>
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
set_error_handler('e_handler',E_ALL);
function e_handler($a,$b,$c,$d){echo $a.' '.$b.' '.$c.' '.$d;die;}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 ob_start();
 print_r($_POST);
 $out1 = ob_get_contents();
 file_put_contents("1.txt",$out1);
 exit;
}


but the error is same. I have also tried to delete everything and  tried with writing nothing to the post capture code. Still that is returning the same error. So style definition & submit - server error 403. No clue !